# Displaying utf8 on flash?

Tags: php, flash, actionscript

I am using flash to read contents from a UTF8 page, which has unicode in it.
The problem is that when Flash loads the data it displays ???????? instead all unicode.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Flash treats strings as if they are encoded using UTF-8. The reason that you are seeing characters that possibly substitute non-printable characters or invalid / missing glyphs could be that you set `System.useCodepage` to `true` - if that's what happened, then why did you do that?

Otherwise, the font that is used to display the characters may be missing glyphs for the characters you need. You can check that by using `Font.hasGlyphs("string with the glyphs");` to make sure the text can be displayed. This would normally only apply to embedded fonts.

Yet another possibility is that the source text you are trying to display is not a UTF-8 encoded string. Some particularly popular file formats such as XML and HTML some times use a declaration of the format in no correspondence to the actual payload (example XML tag: `<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>` can be attached to any XML regardless of the actual encoding of the document). In order to make sure that the text is in UTF-8 - read it as ByteArray and verify that the first bit of every byte is set to 0. Single-byte encodings that use national characters use the first bit to encode their characters, while UTF-8 never does that.

Answer (score 1):

Flash internally uses UTF-8 to represent strings, so there should not be a problem if the entire stack uses UTF-8 encoding.

You probably have an implicit decode/encode step somewhere along the way.
This could really be a million things, unfortunately.  Start from the ground up, insert traces and/or log messages to see where the conversion fails.  Make sure your XML-content uses UTF-8, and especially if you're using PHP, make sure that all the PHP source files are saved in UTF-8 encoding - editing PHP files in simple text editors often results in Windows/Mac format source files, which will then break your character encoding. Also, verify HTML request/response headers to see if there is an encoding mismatch.